# Is "unexpected repercussion" repetitive?

Tags: word-choice, pleonasms

Is the phrase *unexpected repercussion* unnecessary redundantly repetitive?

When I looked up *repercussion* I see that *unexpected* is implicit in its meaning. Should I prefer to say *unexpected consequence*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  You can have expected repercussions.  For example, if you steal something, one of the reasonably expected repercussions is that you'll find yourself in court, if not jail, because of your action.  What might be an unexpected repercussion is that you are wrestled to the ground by an alert rugger player who sees you stealing the object.

Answer (score 3):

It does not seem particularly redundant to me, and I do not think it is a blatant tautology. In addition, at least one dictionary (NOAD) does not define it as *unexpected*, but as *unintended*, which is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Merriam Webster defines it as a "reciprocal action; a widespread, indirect, or unforseen effect." I don't think it's necessarily redundant.